# Detect collisions between my bullet and food

Tags: flash, actionscript, collision, detection

I am making this game, I want to detect collisions between my bullet and my food. 
I don't understand how I can make my food react to my bullet and with that make a score.

Can someone explain to me how to do this or point me in some direction.

```
stop();

import flash.events.MouseEvent;

// maak nieuw kanon aan
var Player:player = new player();

// set de coordinaten van het kanon
Player.x = 425;
Player.y = 540;

// creeer het kanon
addChild(Player);

var score = 0;
score_txt.text = score;


//functie pijltjes besturing
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,reportKeyDown); 
function reportKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void 
{ 
var i:int; 
var options_num:int = 3;

// coordinaten pijltje naar links
if(event.keyCode == 37)
{
    Player.x -= 50
}
// coordinaten pijltje naar rechts 
if(event.keyCode == 39)
{
    Player.x += 50
}
// coordinaten pijltje naar rechts 
if(event.keyCode == 32)
{
    shoot()
}

// gooi random het eten door de lucht :)
i = Math.round(Math.random() * (options_num-1) + 1);
if(i == 1)
{
    eten()
}
} 

// vork schieten
function shoot(e:Event = null):void {
// maak nieuw vork aan
var Bullet:bullet = new bullet();

// zet coordinaten van de vork hetzelfde als het kanon
Bullet.x = Player.x+6;
Bullet.y = Player.y-20;

// creeer de vork
addChild(Bullet);
Bullet.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, function(e:Event):void {
    // laat fork bewegen
    movebullet(e)

})
 }
// snelheid schieten vork
function movebullet(e:Event):void {
e.target.y -= 60;
if(e.target.y <= 50) {
    e.target.removeEventListener(e.type, movebullet);
}
}

// eten schieten
function eten(e:Event = null):void {
// maak nieuw vork aan
var foodArray = new Array(kip, hamburger, pizza, patat, ijs);
var nummer = Math.floor(Math.random() * foodArray.length);
var Eten:MovieClip = new foodArray[nummer];

// coordinaten van het eten
Eten.x = 750;
Eten.y = randomMinMax(30, 70);

// creeer eten
addChild(Eten);
Eten.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, function(e:Event):void {
    // laat fork bewegen
    gooieten(e)
})
}
// snelheid schieten eten
function gooieten(e:Event):void {
e.target.x -= 20;
e.target.y += 0;
if(e.target.x <= 50) {
    e.target.removeEventListener(e.type, gooieten);
}
}



// random getallen creeren (gebruikt bij schieten van verschillende soorten eten)
function randomMinMax(min:Number, max:Number):Number
{
 return min + (max - min) * Math.random();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function that you are looking for is `hitTestObject()`. However, this will require a little modification to your code.

We need a way to reference our bullets and food after we have created them. To do that, we will make containers `foodContainer` and `bulletContainer`. These will hold all of the food and the bullets respectively.

```
import flash.display.Sprite

var foodContainer:Sprite = new Sprite()
var bulletContainer:Sprite = new Sprite()
addChild(foodContainer)
addChild(bulletContainer)
```

We always have a reliable reference to these containers, and we can access them whenever we need to. Now, whenever we make a new bullet or food, we will add it to a container instead of adding it to the stage.

```
function shoot(e:Event = null):void {
    // make new bullet
    var Bullet:bullet = new bullet();

    //set bullet coordinates
    Bullet.x = Player.x+6;
    Bullet.y = Player.y-20;

    // add the bullet TO THE BULLETCONTAINER
    bulletContainer.addChild(Bullet);
}
```

(I have changed this to English)

```
function addFood(e:Event = null):void
{
    //make new food
    var foodArray = new Array(kip,hamburger,pizza,patat,ijs);
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * foodArray.length);
    var food:MovieClip = new foodArray[randomNumber];

    // set coordinate of food
    food.x = 750;
    food.y = randomMinMax(30,70);

    // add the food TO THE FOODCONTAINER
    foodContainer.addChild(food);   
}
```

Okay, so we have all of our assets stored into three things; the `bulletContainer`, the `foodContainer`, and the `stage`(which holds your player).
Now we can set up the collision handling

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,testCollision)

function testCollision(e:Event = null) {
    //for each bullet in the bulletContainer...
    for (var i=0;i<=bulletContainer.numChildren-1;i++) {
        //and for each food in the foodContainer...
        for (var j=0;i<=foodContainer.numChildren-1;j++) {
            //we use getChildAt() to reference each child
            //(a bullet is a child of the bulletContainer; you get the idea)
            var targetBullet = bulletContainer.getChildAt(i)
            var targetFood = foodContainer.getChildAt(j)
            //heres the magic statement, hitTestObject()
            if (targetBullet.hitTestObject(targetFood) {
                //do some action to increase the score
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the code above, for every bullet in the `bulletContainer`, we cycle through every food in the `foodContainer`, and check to see if they are touching or not.
Then, we do whatever you want with the score and we're done!

However, there are some drawbacks to using `hitTestObject()`. This page give an explanation why.
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-collision-detection-between-circles--active-10523